# Some problems when running spring-cloud-stream-samples

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I running the application https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/stream-listener , met some errors ,why ?

```
    Sending value: hi of type class demo.domain.Foo
2016-04-07 19:19:50.811 ERROR 76016 --- [hannel-adapter1] o.s.c.s.b.r.RedisMessageChannelBinder$2  : Failed to deliver message; retries exhausted; message sent to queue 'ERRORS:testtock.anonymous.61fc01c4-17a1-46b5-9579-286413dc45e0' 

org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found to convert to class demo.domain.Bar, message=GenericMessage [payload=hi, headers={contentType=text/plain, id=72274970-5e79-a8ef-d3f1-fcd4ede2fa55, timestamp=1460027990799}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:118) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:98) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.0.RC1.jar!/:1.0.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

The whole code and error details is in https://github.com/keryhu/spring-stream-transform-converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you try to send String as the message while you expect that to be converted to Bar. In your context, you only have `FooToBarConverter`, hence you would need to send `Foo` as the message payload in your source.

If your source looks like this:

```
return new MessageSource<Foo>() {
        public Message<Foo> receive() {
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println("At the Source");
            System.out.println("******************");
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setValue("hi");
            System.out.println("Sending value: " + foo.getValue() + " of type " + foo.getClass());
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(foo).build();
        }
    };
```

then that would work. Otherwise, you would need a converter that converts `String` to `Bar`.

Comment: yes, `after changing Message<String> to Message<Foo> `, it works ,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `ConverterConfig` doesn't get picked up. In the samples, all the configuration classes are in the same package as that of the `@SpringBootApplication` main class `TypeConversionApplication.java` so that ComponentScan is done for all the classes in that package. You need to make sure the converter is in the context of your Sink application.

Comment: very strangely , i add `@Configuration` in the `ConverterConfig` , why it can't be ComponentScan by the context

Comment: I think it is because your `ConverterConfig` is not in the same package as that of your `@SpringBootApplication` class. You may have to explicitly add packages for the component scan.

Comment: i put `ConverterConfig` in  the same package `package demo` as `@SpringBootApplication` , but the error is still there ...

Comment: yeah, I missed that in your branch. ComponentScan does work for sub-packages too. So that isn't the problem here.